# How to set C/C++ console text in bold and italic in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am developing an Visual C++ application in windows console mode, I want to set my console text in to Bold and Italic form.
I changed console text color and background color using `SetConsoleTextAttribute` function and `system("COLOR XX")` functions.

But there is no **Win32 API** function to changed text mode in to BOLD, Italic or Stroke.

Please mention any function or mechanism to achieve it within C/C++ programming boundary in Windows environment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997096/bold-output-in-c

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall in second answer of that question he mentioned "For example, in Window's console, there's no way to write a text in bold." :( Is that the verdict?

Comment: [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @RbMm yeah it helps to bold the fonts but how to achieve italic, under stroking ?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use the wrong tool.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what did you mean? If you want to display something clear and descriptive manner in console how do you achieve it?

Comment: Exactly what I said. Why are you attempting to use the console for such a task? The console is for plain text output, not for emulating a GUI. Yes, I know some GUI-like command-line applications exist (e.g. Emacs, Vi, DOS programs from the 1980s) but why not instead use the proper tool for the job? Why do you want italics and underlines?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with your argument but dear Friend my application just a console app' ,but I need to provide some colorize and descriptive information display within console ... to QA guys :| that's why...

Comment: I don't understand where italics and underline come into that. If you want to display heavily formatted text, write a GUI application. Also since we have never met I do not think you can count me as a dear friend :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit okey non dear Friend, stick to the point, if  there is no such functionality exposed through Win32 API ,we cannot achieve this,, but Linux/UNIX environment this can be achieved I saw some articles .

Comment: You're not listening to what I'm saying, but that's okay. Good luck.

Comment: console(current implementation) not support italic or underline. only `PCWSTR FaceName, UCHAR FontFamily, LONG FontWeight, COORD dwFontSize` - this

Comment: @RbMm Thank for the info.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Got Luck with HTML :D

Comment: I've got a console written from the ground up in my Baby X project. You can modify to create your own. https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyx/blob/master/src/widgets/bbx_console.c

Answer (score 4):

This can't be done in Windows with the standard console. Either write your own console-looking thing that *does* support bold/italic, etc., or use a graphical UI.

There are many ways to design a UI in Windows. If you're using C++, you can use MFC or ATL/WTL. If you're prepared to interface with .NET, you can use Windows Forms or WPF. It's been a couple of years since I did any Windows development, but you can probably write a UWP app in C++.

Consider whether you need output like this at all. You might be able to get away with generating HTML-formatted reports that people can look at in their web browser.

Or maybe you can run a local web server, and use the user's browser for your UI.

Comment: you answer has great idea!! thank you.Can you please mentioned me  any popular and great tool to generate such HTML report and can be integrated with C/C++ App? like Intel Inspector Anlysis tool/VTune Ampliefier tools is doing ?

Comment: No, because that's out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why is that? is that violating rules? or something?

Comment: *"you can probably write a UWP app in C++"* - That's correct. You can use Microsoft's [C++/CX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699871.aspx) Component Extension, choose [WRL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx), or go with [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt) (the latter being available as a Preview Release).

Comment: @BuddhikaGamage, yes, asking for software recommendations is off-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @llnspectable Thanks for the info

Answer (score -1):

To write in bold, you can use:

```
std::cout << "\e[1mbold text here\e[0m" << std::endl;
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. `\e` is not a valid escape sequence. If you were to use `\x1b`, this wouldn't work either. You'd have to enable [`ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) first. If you did, this still wouldn't work reliably. You'd have to call `WriteFile` or `WriteConsole`.

Comment: And if you did all of the above, this would still not produce a bold font face. Bold really means [Applies brightness/intensity flag to foreground color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting).