# How would I make text bold & colored at the same time in c++ (linux)

Tags: c++, colors, ansi-escape, bold

I am trying to output text to the console with both bold and colored properties. I can make the text output bold with this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "\e[1m" << "bold" << "\e[0m" << " non-bold" << std::endl;
}
```

And I can make colored text like so:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "\033[34;40m" << "text" << "\033[0m" << std::endl;
}
```

But I am having trouble making text with both bold & colored properties.
Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997157/260313

Answer (score 0):

It should work either with 2 sequences, the one for bold and the one for color, used one after the other:

```
std::cout << "\033[1m\033[34;40m" << ...
```

or with bold and color combined in one sequence:

```
std::cout << "\033[1;34;40m" << ...
```

Comment: this worked perfectly in combo with my overall project! thanks!